# find the derivative of a function with more than one variable

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

I have a function $g(a)=f_i(x+a(y-x))$ where a$\in$$\Re$ and x,y$\in \Re^d$.

How can I find the first and the second derivative of this function?

The second part of the exercise is asking me to use the Taylor's theorem for g near a=0 to second order.
I consider $g'(a)=f'_i(x+a(y-x))(y-x)$ and $g''(a)=f''_i(x+a(y-x))$
Then I have to plug them in the Taylor's series equation.
Is that the correct way?
Could you please help how it will look like on the Taylor's series formula?

Comment: It's not stated what $i$ means here. Is $g$ a real-valued function of $a$?

Comment: My exercise is stated as here.  Nothing is stated about i.

Comment: What is the range of $g$?

Comment: again this is not stated

Comment: This problem seems ill-defined. @Mher assumed that $f_i$ is real-valued then used the chain rule. Other than that the only response people can make is "use the chain rule".

Comment: @SuzuHirose: Don't say people what they can response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:

the first derivative of $g(a) = f(x + a(y-x))$ is
$$g'(a) = f'_{x_1}(x + a(y-x))\cdot (y_1-x_1) + \dots + f'_{x_d}(x + a(y-x))\cdot (y_d-x_d) =$$
$$= \vec\nabla f(x + a(y-x))\cdot(y-x)$$

Comment: It says $g=f_i$ with a subscript $i$ but there is no explanation of what $i$ is or what the range of $f$ is.

Comment: what does this symbol mean? (opposite delta)

Comment: That is gradient of a multivariable function. It's vector whose $k$th item is the derivative of $f$ with respect to its $k$th variable.

Comment: @Mher How can I use g'(a) and g''(a) in order to write Taylor's series for g near a=0 to second order ??

Comment: Like this $$g(x) = g(a)+\frac{g'(a)}{1!}(x-a)+\frac{g''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2+o\left((x-a)^2\right)$$

Comment: @Mher : is the term $0((x-1)^2)$ the remainder? If not, what is the remainder for the second order term?

Answer (score 0):

Since $g$ is a function of a real variable $a$, you can find ${dg\over da}$ by the usual methods of differentiation, treating all the $x$ and $y$ components as constants. If they are not constant but functions of $a$, then just use the chain rule.